# Validity of Probability Mass Functions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Determine the values of k and $\alpha$ which make the following pmfs valid:
$$f(n) = \frac{k}{n(n+1)}, \,\, n = 1,2,3,\,\, ... $$
$$f(n) = kn^{\alpha},\,\, n = 1,2,3,\,\, ... $$

I know a valid pmf must abide by the following rules:

1) $f(n) \geq 0$

2) $\sum_n f(n) = 1$

**Attempted Solution**:

I believe the first one is rather straight forward since:
$$k \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = k*1 = 1 $$ by the second property.

For the second one, it has the form of a Zeta distribution, but I am stuck on the process to solve for both $k$ and $\alpha$ simultaneously.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** For the second, recall the $p$-test: for which $p$ is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ finite? ($p$ is $-\alpha$ in your problem).

Once you know for which $\alpha$ we have a finite sum, you can get the normalizing constant as simply being the reciprocal of the sum (which is a function of $\alpha$, in fact $\zeta(-\alpha)$).

If the sum is infinite, it won't be a valid PMF, as you should be able to argue.

Comment: $\text{Correct!}$

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I forgot it was $n^\alpha$ and not $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ in the problem.